# assignment_code needs to be unique but I dont want it to

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE assignment (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(10),
    course_code VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code, assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code));
```

But when I try to create it PostgreSQL tells me assignment_code needs to be unique. However my assignment is to make assignment_code unique per course in stead of completely unique, how do I do that?

the code below creates the enitre database (no data)

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(15),
    surname VARCHAR(35),
    enrollment_year INT,
    bsn BIGINT,
    class VARCHAR(5),
    Graduated BOOLEAN);
CREATE TABLE teachers (
     bsn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
     first_name VARCHAR(15),
     surname VARCHAR(35),
     salary REAL,
     scale INT,
     CONSTRAINT salary CHECK(salary < (25 * scale) AND salary > (20 *     scale)));
CREATE TABLE course (
     course_code VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
     course_name VARCHAR(20),
     course_follower VARCHAR(5),
     study_points INT,
     Amount_of_assignments INT);
CREATE TABLE teaches (
     bsn BIGINT,
     class VARCHAR(5),
     course_code VARCHAR(10),
     PRIMARY KEY(bsn, class, course_code),
     FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
     FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code));
CREATE TABLE study_program (
     course_name VARCHAR(20),
     course_code VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
     level VARCHAR(15),
     duration VARCHAR(10),
     FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code));
CREATE TABLE assignment (
     assignment_code VARCHAR(10),
     course_code VARCHAR(10),
     PRIMARY KEY(course_code, assignment_code),
     FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code));
CREATE TABLE records (
     student_id BIGINT,
     course_code VARCHAR(20),
     school VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY(student_id, course_code),
     FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
     FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES study_program(course_code));
CREATE TABLE make (
     student_id BIGINT,
     assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
     completed BOOLEAN,
     PRIMARY KEY(student_id, assignment_code),
     FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
     FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code));
CREATE TABLE prerequisit (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
    prerequisit_code VARCHAR(20),
    course_code VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(assignment_code, course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(prerequisit_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code));
CREATE TABLE records_2 (
    assignment_code VARCHAR(20),
    course_code VARCHAR(20),
    bsn BIGINT,
    mandatory BOOLEAN,
    year INT,
    week INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(assignment_code, course_code, bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn));    
CREATE TABLE designes (
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    bsn BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn));    
CREATE TABLE reviews (
    bsn BIGINT,
    course_code VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY(bsn, course_code),
    FOREIGN KEY(bsn) REFERENCES teachers(bsn),
    FOREIGN KEY(course_code) REFERENCES course(course_code));
```

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.6

Comment: Your `create table` should be fine.  Edit your question and include the code that is generating the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lurking deep in your code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE records_2 
    . . .
    FOREIGN KEY(assignment_code) REFERENCES assignment(assignment_code),
```

A foreign key reference needs to be to a unique or primary key.  If you have a composite primary key, then you need to use all the keys.  Hence, this reference is missing `course_code`.

I am a strong believer in synthetic primary keys -- that is, serial integer columns that provide this information.  I would recommend that you use them in your table and for foreign key references.

Comment: This is awesome advice actually, Ill keep it in mind!